# Rails 4 how to change structure of validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to change the structure of general validation errors for JSON such as

presence and uniqueness

I have below code in model folder with presence_validator.rb

```
class PresenceValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value.present?
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not present")
    end
  end
end
```

But this doesn't seem to be working with message.

I would like the error format to be like:

```
{
  "errors": [
     { "key": "aaass", "value": "adasasdas" },
     { "key": "aadaass", "value": "adasas132das" }
  ]
}
```

Current JSON fail:

```
{
  "name": [
    "Requires name"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show what the current JSON string you get for a validation fail with at least two errors looks like?  Also, if you're going to use `is not present` in one example it's best to use that in the other rather than keymashing.

Comment: You are trying to access `record.errors[:errors]` as it was `Hash` instance (`record.errors[:errors][attribute]`) while you want it to be an array.

Comment: In cases like this there is always one question which have be asked: WHY?

Comment: @mudasobwa I just updated my question.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I just added current JSON as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly - it is not a correct place for this change. Error structure should stay as it is, you want to change errors json representation. For this you need some monkey patching:

```
class ActiveModel::Errors
  def as_json(options={})
    {
      errors: map {|key, value| {key: key, value: value } }
    }
  end
end
```

place this code in `config/initializers/errors_extensions.rb` and all should work according to specs.